# How can I make Vim autoread a file while it doesn't have focus?

Tags: filesystem

I'm using VIm for all kinds of things (or gVim in this case), including monitoring output written to a file; I use `autoread` to make Vim reread the file, which it does whenever I switch the keyboard focus to it.

Is there any way to make Vim update the buffer even if I don't switch the keyboard focus? I've tried setting `checktime` but it doesn't appear to have any effect while keyboard focus is elsewhere.

The output I'm monitoring is replacing the output file completely; and I'm not looking to `tail -f` it. There are other options, like piping into a new instance every time, or piping into `less` or something, but it'd be cool if it could be done with VIm.

Comment: See also: [Can vim monitor realtime changes to a file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157914/can-vim-monitor-realtime-changes-to-a-file/18866818#18866818)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`:help 'autoread'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autoread%27) doesn't have a lot of information on how it works, but Vim checks if an open file is modified in certain events (it always does this), and will reload it automatically if `autoread` is abled.

Specifically, it checks when:

- `:checktime` is used;
- a buffer is entered;
- `:diffupdate` is used;
- `:e` is issued for a file that already has a buffer;
- executing an external command with `!`;
- returning to the foreground (`^Z`, `fg`, only if the shell has job control);

for gVim, this is also done when:

- closing the "right-click" menu (either by selecting something, or just by closing it);
- focus is changed (this is what you already noticed);
- closing the file browsers dialog that pops up if you use "file -> open", "file -> save as" from the menu (as well as some other places).

I gathered this information from the Vim source by locating all calls to the `buf_check_timestamp()`, `check_timestamps()` functions, and locations where `need_check_timestamps` is set to `TRUE`. This list may be outdated because I looked at it 2015, but at a quick glance it seems to still be (mostly) accurate.

The key thing is that Vim only checks if the file is modified in a very limited set of circumstances. This makes sense, because polling a potentially large number of buffers every *n* seconds can be rather expensive.

Since Vim 7.4.1578 (March 2016) there are timers, which you can use to run `checktime` every *n* seconds (a previous version of this answer from 2015 used hackish workarounds).

For example, to do this only for certain buffers you can use something like:

```
set autoread
fun! s:checktime(timer_id)
    checktime
endfun
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost xxx
            \ call timer_start(3000, function('s:checktime'), {'repeat': -1})
```

This has the disadvantage of setting a lot of timers, so perhaps a better method is to set one which loops over all the buffers and then sets the timer again (so you don't risk having two run simultaneously):

```
set autoread
fun! s:checktime(timer_id)
    for buf in filter(map(getbufinfo(), {_, v -> v.bufnr}), {_, v -> buflisted(v)})
        echom buf
        exe 'checktime' buf
    endfor
    call timer_start(3000, function('s:checktime'))
endfun
call timer_start(3000, function('s:checktime'))
```

I did notice Vim blinks a bit even if nothing changes; not sure if there's a way to work around that (didn't look at it); so you might want to add it as a command to run only when needed:

```
set autoread
let s:autoread_timer = -1
fun! s:checktime(timer_id)
    checktime
endfun

command! -bang Autoread 
            \  if <bang>0
            \|   call timer_stop(s:autoread_timer)
            \| else
            \|   let s:autoread_timer = timer_start(1000,
            \        function('s:checktime'), {'repeat': -1})
            \| endif
```

There are many ways to improve on this further, such as enabling it only for the current buffer, more control on how often to run, etc. etc. but the idea should be clear :-)

Answer (score 4):

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296697/4940240) (refering to an answer by [PhanHaiQuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2467354/phan-hai-quang) and a comment by [flukus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407256/flukus))

One can run this oneliner from ex (whithin vim) when needed (or put each command in vimrc, for when log-files are opened.)

`:set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("lh")`

Explanation:
- **autoread**: reads the file when changed from the outside (but it doesnt work on its own, there is no internal timer or something like that. It will only read the file when vim does an action, like a command in ex `:!`
- **CursorHold * checktime**: when the cursor isn't moved by the user for the time specified in 'updatetime' (which is 4000 miliseconds by default) checktime is executed, which checks for changes from outside the file
- **call feedkeys("lh")**: the cursor is moved once, right and back left. and then nothing happens (... which means, that CursorHold is triggered, which means we have a **loop**)

Answer (score 3):

I made a little plugin [vim-autoread](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-autoread/) that uses `tail -f` to update the buffer in the background asynchronously. This needs obviously the job feature of Vim Version 8.

Use `:AutoRead` to turn it on and `:AutoRead!` to turn it off.

Comment: A NeoVim-compatible version would be great!

Comment: @AndrewMacFie I don't see, why this wouldn't work on Neovim.

Comment: the lack of Vim 8 jobs support in NeoVim I thought?

Comment: @AndrewMacFie oh that is probably be true. Since  I don't use neovim, I cannot make it NeoVim compatible. However a PR would be welcome :)

Comment: fair enough : )

Comment: :h vim-autoread is not working in MacVim 8.0.1522 on mac os 10.13.3 High Sierra. However, the plugin is working great! Thank you @ChristianBrabandt

Answer (score 1):

In Neovim you could use the following command which will open a terminal buffer running the tail command.

```
:enew | call termopen('tail --follow=name --retry /path/to/file.log')
```

This will continue to work even if the file is removed and recreated.

Or add the following to your `$MYVIMRC`

```
" :Tail /path/to/file
function! Tail(file)
  enew
  call termopen('tail --follow=name --retry ' . fnameescape(a:file))
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Tail call Tail(<f-args>)
```