# How can I have vim automatically notify me when a file that I am editing changes?

Tags: save

I have a situation where sometimes my friend and I are working in the same file at the same time.

Vim will tell me if the file has changed when I try to overwrite it.  Can I have vim notify me as soon as the file changes, all by itself, before I save?

Comment: What do you want to happen if you've both changed the same line?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Hmmm... Hard one.  Maybe it could just pop up a message or something.  I'm open to suggestions on that.

Comment: But what would be the desired behavior you're expecting? That Vim not just reload the changes but to actually shows something like a desktop popup message or avoid Vim to automatically reloads the changes and shows a warning message instead letting you decide what to do?

Comment: @JavierScappini Either.  I'm not that picky.  I guess it would be cool to have it automatically load the changes...

Comment: My [answer here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2731/51) has some info about the `autoread` setting & it's limitations ... possibly this is also an answer for this question?

Comment: Have you considered using a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) to manage the shared files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try the `autoread` option? From [`:help 'autoread'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autoread%27):

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.

Comment: Note that `autoread` is rather limited; it only checks if the file is changed when certain events occur. [Also see my answer here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2731/51).

Answer (score 4):

This question has been answered in StackOverflow: [How does Vim's autoread work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490227/how-does-vims-autoread-work)

## Solution 1

Follow explanations in Vim Wikia page [Have Vim check automatically if the file has changed externally](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Have_Vim_check_automatically_if_the_file_has_changed_externally).
This solution requires the addition of a function to your vimrc file and that a new command is called on the buffers you want to watch.

## Solution 2

This solution was proposed by @GregSexton in the question I linked above. The idea is to force the modification check whenever one of the following happens:

- Entering the buffer.
- No key was pressed for ['updatetime'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27updatetime%27)
- Cursor moved.

You can find the code that implements this below:

```
augroup checktime
    au!
    if !has("gui_running")
        "silent! necessary otherwise throws errors when using command
        "line window.
        autocmd BufEnter        * silent! checktime
        autocmd CursorHold      * silent! checktime
        autocmd CursorHoldI     * silent! checktime
        "these two _may_ slow things down. Remove if they do.
        autocmd CursorMoved     * silent! checktime
        autocmd CursorMovedI    * silent! checktime
    endif
augroup END
```

Add and/or remove `autocmd` as best suits your workflow. Check [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events) for the list of events that can be used.

If [autoread](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoread%27) is also enabled, file will be automatically read if not modified:

```
set autoread
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some modes (eg in `ex` mode, entered by a command starting with `:`) in which the check shouldn't fire.

Here's what I came up with to avoid checks in unwanted modes:

```
" Trigger `checktime` when files changes on disk
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI *
        \ if mode() !~ '\v(c|r.?|!|t)' && getcmdwintype() == '' | checktime | endif
```