# Keep buffer current without manual refresh?

Tags: buffers, save, persistent-state

Sometimes I'll edit a file I'm working on in another editor (don't ask) but it will be open in vim or vice versa.

With vim I need to `:e` to force a refresh of the file. However in my other editors the text updates automatically.

Is it possible to have vim keep files current with their saved state automatically?

Comment: Using `set autoread` sort of does this, but has limitations. See [my answer here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2731/51), which also includes a possible solution.

Comment: Also very similar to: [How can I have vim automatically notify me when a file that I am editing changes?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2709/51)