# How to allow editing of a file from other sources while it's already open in vim?

Tags: swap-file

Let's say I have a text file opened in vim. I'd like to be able to edit this file from bash, let's say with the command `echo "text" >> file` while the file is already opened in vim. Ideally, vim would just refresh the new content and wouldn't bother with a .swp file, asking for what version I want to restore. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the option you're looking for is `autoread`. To use it put this in your `vimrc`:

```
set autoread
```

From `:h 'autoread'`:

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
>     it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
>     When the file has been deleted this is not done.

Comment: I don't see text updating in vim when I append text from bash to opened file

Comment: It only updates when vim gets focus again. I don't think there's a way to make it update when it doesn't have focus.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs See: [How can I make Vim autoread a file while it doesn't have focus?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2702/51)